# Only Root Can Mount on Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, debian, mount, bittorrent, transmission

I am new to UNIX and I have been trying to setup Transmission on my new Raspberry Pi. I have formatted my external USB drive to `ext4` and added the following line to the `/etc/fstab`.

```
/dev/sda1         /media/USB96    ext4    defaults           0       0
```

It works fine but when I login as `pi` (instead of `root`) it returns an error when mounting the drive

```
mount: only root can do that
```

I'm stuck here because when I try to download a torrent with the Transmission web interface it also returns an error:

```
Permission denied (/media/USB96/torrents/complete/my torrent link)
```

Please help me to solve this problem and tell me how to allow the normal user `pi` to mount and have access to the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `/etc/fstab` entry to this:

```
/dev/sda1         /media/USB96    ext4    defaults,user           0       0
```

According to the `fstab(5)` manpage, the `user` option allows any user to mount the file system.

Comment: This is the "proper" way to do it.
Alternatively, if the device names aren't predictable, use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

ext4 (and indeed most *nix-native filesystems) are not meant to be used on removable media for not only the reason you've found, but also because of things such as user and group IDs. Reformat the drive to something foreign, such as VFAT or NTFS.

Comment: If i format it to NTFS and use ntfs-3g instead of ext4.. Will it auto mount on user "pi"?

Comment: Depends on other factors.

Comment: Which factor, will you please explain?

Comment: Whether or not you're running anything that will automount it.

Comment: If you have any good tutorial in mind on how to setup transmission with external usb, please tell me.

Comment: Transmission doesn't get "setup" with an external USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

The `pi` user shouldn't need to mount the USB drive. By adding that line to the `/etc/fstab` file, the USB drive will be automatically mounted when the Pi boots up.

The problem you are experiencing is with permissions. The `root` user is likely the owner of `/mnt/USB96`, unless you explicitly changed it. This means that, unless the permissions have been altered for the directory, only `root` can create new files/folders within. This can be verified with

```
$ ls -l /media/USB96
```

To change the owner of `/media/USB96` and all of the subdirectories withen to `pi` so that Tranmission can write to the directory, execute the following as `root` with the USB drive mounted:

```
# chown -R pi:pi /media/USB96
```

Then try downloading a torrent again.

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: help me please!

Comment: Sorry. I meant `/media/` instead of `/mnt/`. Check my edit above. If you noticed this already, as `pi`, can you `cd /media/USB96` and create a file with `touch test.file`? If not, what error does it throw?